# react native webview limitations

Tags: react-native, webview

I have strange problem with webview in react native.
Some pages, which are made in reactjs are not visible in webview

For example this code

```
 <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://cassetterocks.github.io/react-infinite-scroller/demo/'}} 
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
        />
```

is working without problems and the page appears in webview and is visible in app.
But when i change it to this

```
 <WebView
          source={{uri: 'http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-calendar/'}} 
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
        />
```

nothing is displayed, only white screen.

Has webview some special limitations or does somebody know reason for this behavior?
Thank you

EDIT:
After lot of attemps a realized that problem is not in react native but in react  js. I found  few pages in react-js based on this configuration

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
```

and they working without problem in webviews

but pages based on this configuration

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
  }
```

are problematic.
  But i don't known if the problem is in react version or webpack version :-(

FINAL EDIT:
Problem is in probably in react version, with 15.3.2 is everything ok, with 16.2.0 webview display nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView has all sorts of limits that have plagued hybrid developers for a decade now.  I'm not aware of a comprehensive list of all the hairs it will make you pull out.  It's generally a whack-a-mole exercise I'm afraid.  Here's an article which will point to some of the pitfalls... http://undefinedvalue.com/beware-lure-ios-uiwebview.html

As your googling you may see references to Apple fixing these problems in WKWebView but alas this has it's own problems discussed in this React Native github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/321